# MVC 5 - How to create a portable custom control (partial)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I wish to create a custom control to be shared across multiple MVC projects. This custom control is just (to my mind) a partial view with a model and business logic in the classes behind it. The MVC websites can include a reference to this class library and in their `.cshtml` simply call `@Html.Partial("CoolControl").`

What I'm trying right now is a Class Library project, with `MVC -> Models folder` with my model code and a Views folder with the control's .cshtml code.

If I remember correctly, partials go in the `Views\Shared` folder of a MVC website, so they get found. But here the partial lives outside of that.

How do I tell MVC to look in the external library for the partial view? Is this even the best way to do this?

Is there a much better way of creating portable controls in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share partial views for multiple projects in a class library is not that simple.
First you need to create a virtual file and a virtual provider

```
public class AspNetVirtualFile : VirtualFile
{
private string path;

public AspNetVirtualFile(string virtualPath)
    : base(virtualPath)
{
    path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(virtualPath);
}

public override System.IO.Stream Open()
{
    var parts = path.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var assemblyName = parts[2];
    var resourceName = parts[3];

    assemblyName = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, assemblyName);
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName + ".dll");

    if (assembly != null)
    {
        return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

The VirtualProvider

```
public class AspNetVirtualProvider : VirtualPathProvider
{
public const string StartPath = "~/UserControls/";
public const string Path = "~/UserControls/{0}/{1}";

public AspNetVirtualProvider() { }

private bool IsEmbeddedResourcePath(string virtualPath)
{
    try
    {
        var checkPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(virtualPath);
        return checkPath.StartsWith(StartPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    return false;
}

public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
{
    return IsEmbeddedResourcePath(virtualPath) || base.FileExists(virtualPath);
}

public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
{
    if (IsEmbeddedResourcePath(virtualPath))
    {
        return new AspNetVirtualFile(virtualPath);
    }
    else
    {
        return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
    }
}

public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
{
    if (IsEmbeddedResourcePath(virtualPath))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
    }
}
}
```

See that the provider will find for files inside UserControls folder in that shared .dll, you can change if you want.
In the Global.asax Application_Start:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new AspNetVirtualProvider());
```

Create an HtmlHelper, don´t forget the using System.Web.Mvc.Html:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
public static void SharedRenderPartial(this HtmlHelper h, string assemblyName, string fileName, object model)
{
    h.RenderPartial(String.Format(AspNetVirtualProvider.Path, assemblyName, fileName), model);
}
}
```

Now in your View you can do:

```
@{ Html.SharedRenderPartial("My.Qualified.Assembly", String.Format("My.Qualified.Assembly.UserControls.{0}", "_ViewName.cshtml"), Model); }
```

Now you create a cshtml in a UserControls folder in your My.Qualified.Assembly project, you need to change the file BuildAction to EmbededResource. In your view you will need to explicity add the using and the @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage too.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you went to with your answer, but it quickly tells me that it is overkill for what I want to achieve.

Comment: This configuration you need to do only once, after that you just need to use. If I understood your question, your views are in a different project right? The overkill you said is the solution that I did or you will give up to put the usercontrols in a different library? Another way to do is copy as link your shared files to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that create your class library is not a good way to create custom controlls. It's way better to create [nuget package](http://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package). It allows you to add some additional files to project folders and solve problem with dependencies and future updates of your controls.

If you whould like to search for your  `PartialViews` in different than default folder than, the best solution will be inherit from `RazorViewEngine`, create your own routings and register it in MVC `ViewEngines`. Here is a [good article](http://www.leonamarant.com/2011/02/17/adding-a-custom-directory-to-razor-view-engine-partial-view-locations-in-asp-net-mvc3/) how to do it.

Comment: Actually to search for them in another folder you can create your own ViewEngine (just derive from RazorViewEngine) and tell it where to look. Then register it in Application_Start().
You are correct in saying though that the class library is not a good way to do it!

Comment: @VictorySaber yeap, you right, it could be much flexible. But could be that you should write a lot of implementation code in that case.